# Optimize SELF-JOIN in MySQL. Prompts "Lost Connection to MySQL server during Query"

Tags: mysql, sql, join, dml

The table **organiseddata** is designed as with **ID** as Primary key and using a secondary index ***caseindex*** on **CaseID**. The table contains about 5M rows and about 47000 unique CaseIDs.

```
ID     | CaseID  | Actor | Activity

1      | Case1   | John  | A
2      | Case1   | Sean  | C
3      | Case1   | John  | B
4      | Case2   | John  | A
5      | Case2   | Ben   | F
6      | Case2   | Brad  | B
7      | Case2   | John  | E
```

I have a stored procedure that executes join within each case. the caseID are passed as parameter ***currentCase***.

```
SELECT T1.ID, T2.ID, (T2.ID-T1.ID) as Diff, T1.Actor FROM
(SELECT * FROM organiseddata use index(caseindex) where CaseID=currentCase) as T1
JOIN
(SELECT * FROM organiseddata use index(caseindex) where CaseID=currentCase) as T2
ON (T2.ID-T1.ID)>=2 AND T1.Actor=T2.Actor AND T1.Activity <> T2.Activity
ORDER BY (T2.ID-T1.ID) DESC;
```

Once ***T1.ID*** and ***T2.ID*** are obtained, I need to find intermediate Actor(s) in between

```
SELECT ID, Actor as IntActor from organiseddata use index(caseindex) where CaseID=currentCase AND ID>T1.ID AND ID<T2.ID;
```

For each such ID found, I need to update the result  into the ***RESULT_TABLE***. The structure of **RESULT_TABLE** for the above table would look like(values not shown). Values for **A,B,C,E,F** are all of type **double**.

```
Actor  | A  | B  | C  | E  | F

A      | -- | ---| -  | -- | --
B      | -- | ---| -  | -- | --
C      | -- | ---| -  | -- | --
E      | -- | ---| -  | -- | --
F      | -- | ---| -  | -- | --
```

Using CONCAT I appended the value of T1.Actor and IntActor into the query(general representation) shown below.

```
INSERT INTO RESULT_TABLE(`T1.Actor`,`IntActor`) values ('',1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `IntActor`=`IntActor`+POW(0.5,Diff-2);
```

But after execution for a while, I get ***"Lost Connection to MySQL server during Query"***. I have already tried increasing ***max_allowed_packet*** to a higher value but to no avail.

What other config values should I change in my.ini file. And is there a better way to perform the join above.

Comment: what does `POW(0.5,Diff-2)` mean ?

Comment: Since the relation between T1.Actor and IntActor may be repeated in some other CaseID (and also multiple times), so I need to make a small addition to the total in the RESULT_TABLE on each occurance. The power function achieves that task.

Comment: is Diff  a keyword?  what dies Diff mean?

Comment: Diff is (T2.ID-T1.ID). The JOIN query above collects this value.

Comment: ah... Sorry, I have no clue.

Comment: `T2.ID - T1.ID` itself is meaningless.  Auto-gen ids should be regarded as essentially random memory-address locations - you have information there, but it's otherwise irrelevant.  For one thing, are you certain that _all_ of a particular `caseId` are consecutive?  Under normal circumstances, I'd anticipate cases being interleaved, and gaps appearing on occasion too.  You'd be better off generating some form of per-case index, based on some natural ordering (time?)

Answer (score 1):

As for the join part of the question, your query can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T2.ID, (T2.ID-T1.ID) as Diff, T1.Actor 
FROM organiseddata as T1
JOIN organiseddata as T2
    ON T2.ID>=T1.ID+2 
   AND T1.Actor=T2.Actor 
   AND T1.Activity <> T2.Activity
   AND T1.CaseID = T2.CaseID
WHERE T1.CaseID=currentCase
```

I would investigate the plan for this and then probably drop the index on caseindex and replace it with:

```
CREATE INDEX ... ON organiseddata (caseindex, Actor, ID, Activity);
```

Compare with the original and see if it helps.

Comment: Shouldn't the new index be on  (CaseID,Actor,ID,Activty) and not what you specified. Will there be any difference when I use index on one Attribute as opposed to multiple attributes?

Comment: @GvanJoic only one index can be used, so if you have a whole bunch of single column indexes, only one of them will be used. The index needs to be created from the most unique to the least unique column.

Comment: @JonathanDahan That makes sense. So the correct secondary index should be on (ID,CaseID,Actor,Activity). But since I already have a PRIMARY KEY for ID, so should I include it in secondary index also?

Comment: having ID at the beginning won't do anything because if it matches something on that it's done since all IDs are unique. I would reconsider your query, as it's never going to perform well the way it's written.

Comment: @GvanJoic, there are several possible indexes. The one I proposed assumes that it is easier to satisfy the predicate T2.ID>=T1.ID+2 than T1.Activity <> T2.Activity. Try both to see which one that works best. Regarding the question whether `ID` should be included or not: as @JonathanDahan points out, mysql can only use one index. Some DBMS can use several indexes and do `INDEX_ANDING` but despite that a single index with more columns is usually much more efficient.

Comment: @GvanJoic: Ooops, I see now that I misread your question. Of course the index should be  (CaseID,Actor,ID,Activty). Somehow I managed to misinterpret that your concern whether ID or Activity should be first in index.